# menu customization

Tags: customization, menus, translation

I am using a premium theme on my page. The theme only accepts one menu in the whole site.

The site is a single page site. And the way the theme works is that we have to set up a Home Page and then use the Menu items in order to make the sections of the site.

So, I created a Menu with all the sections I want to have using pages I created already set up as sections. So for example: I have Home, Photos, Videos, etc. These are individual pages but when I include them as part of the menu they will appear one below the other one in a single page and the menu items will scroll to that anchor on that single page.

Many themes work like that.

**My problem is** :

I need to translate the menu OR set up another page (not as section, but a normal independent page) with a different menu with the items linking to anchors on that page and not the Main Page.

I'm asking this mainly because I want to have the site in two different languages. So I have a main page (In English) with a normal Menu and one of the Items of the Menu is not a section but a link to the second language (Spanish). I can easily make a page and declare it as a Single Page and not a section but then, when the menu appears in that page it's in English and those links are linking to the Main Page sections in English.

I already made the translation myself and I want to have my own translation not an automated one. My page is mainly informative and the text almost never changes.

I do not want to pay for the WPML plugin and the other free plug ins out there aren't any good. It's such a simple thing and I can't find a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if I understand correctly you should create a second menu which is only visible on your Spanish language page.

```
if (is_page($english_page_id)) {
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu'=>$english_menu) );
} 
if (is_page($spanish_page_id)) {
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu'=>$spanish_menu) )
}
```

[`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)
[`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

Comment: Hi Florian,

Thank you for your answer.

I've seen examples like that before.

So, If I did that, where would I paste the code? (I mean which file? - Where about in the file?)

Thank you!

Comment: Search your theme for occurrences of `wp_nav_menu`, then put my code where you want the translated menu to appear.

Answer (score -1):

There are good plugins for this without paying...

But you can also (which you should have already) create a child theme.
Add another menu in the child functions and create custom links.

Keep in mind that this is extremely high-maintenance.

Besides that this is just a crappy work around

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately, there aren't any good free plug-ins that I can use.

In fact, the only plug-in that dos exactly what I need is WPML.

I can't afford to pay for it as it is an annual fee and when you don't pay the whole translation disappears.

Comment: The whole thing doesn't disappears but you just can't update. Anyhow I also like Loco Translate https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

Comment: Yes, I know that one too. But it doesn't do what I need. I don't need localization, or work with PO files nor string translation.

I need to have a way to insert a different menu on a different page under the same site OR translate the whole menu (including the actual links) just for one page only. (The rest will stay as it is. As i explain in my query).